# How to keep history of MySQL/Aurora stored procedure revisions?

Tags: mysql, aurora

We need to maintain the history of the procedures. I think it will be easier to save the history in a table so every time someone either deletes or modifies the content of the procedure it will go and save the changes to a table to maintain an history. May be upto a point a trigger can help, but wanted to check if anyone has any custom script written on this already which can be reviewed?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good StackOverflow post with various answers that might help you: [Put MySQL database under version control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883735/put-mysql-database-under-version-control)

Specifically, [Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/) seems to withstood the test of time, and it seems to be supported by AWS (seeing as you mentioned Aurora): [Deploy, track, and roll back RDS database code changes using open source tools Liquibase and Jenkins](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/rds-code-change-deployment/)

(Note this leverages the Amazon service [CodeCommit](https://aws.amazon.com/codecommit/).)